# Android: Identify what code an AsyncTask is running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In Eclipse in the Debug window I see a thread that shows:

Thread <16> AsyncTask #11

Is there a way to determine what actual section of code the AsyncTask is referring to? Is there something I have to add in code to identify that running thread?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name the Thread of an AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684182/name-the-thread-of-an-asynctask)

Comment: @aleb Usually older posts are not considered duplicates of newer posts, even though the dupe has more views and votes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can name the `AsyncTask` thread at the beginning of your `doInBackground` function:

```
public void doInBackground(Params... params) {
    Thread.currentThread().setName("Foo (AsyncTask)");
    // ... rest of your AsyncTask processing ...
}
```

The specified name will be shown in the Eclipse Debug window, as well as thread list in DDMS perspective.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. However, I noticed that there are AsyncTasks showing up in the Debug window without any naming. I did check all of my code to make sure your suggested code was in all of them. This leads me to believe that some other internal code must be spawing those tasks. Any idea how I can find out who spawned them?

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of. If you really want to deeply investigate that, then you can selectively enable and disable external libraries and system components that you're using in your app, and see how it influences the list of threads.

Comment: It's likely a CursorLoader + CursorAdapter using AsyncTasks internally.