# Name the Thread of an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Is it possible to give a name to an AsyncTask's background thread, as for normal Threads in Java:

```
Thread(Runnable target, String name)
```

I have seen the code of AsyncTask and the default constructor is just give a name by default

```
private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
    }
};
```

I want to do that, as when I debug I want to know which Asynctask is accessing a method in a helper class.

Comment: what do you mean, can't extend? you must extend AsyncTask in order to use it. why not just extend the default constructor, and add a private member "name" which you set in the constructor?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try calling this from inside `doInBackground()`:

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("some custom name");
```

Answer (score -6):

Why can't you extend the AsyncTask I dont understand.

I extend my AsyncTask thousand times with debugger shows me which AsyncTask is bitching.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
}
```

like so

Comment: If I want to extends the class I have to implement doInBackground method, and what about the name? This is not in a default contructor.

Comment: Then create your contructor of MyAsyncTask. When you create the AysncTask, you use new MyAsyncTask(String name) to init your asyncTask. And I still dont understand what you mean by the name of the AsyncTask

Comment: By the name i meant to add a parameter to the class which is the name of the asynctask. As the 1st comment of my question. My idea is to add the name when i create the new Thread "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement() + name); for example.